# Python - How to parse Boolean Sympy tree expressions to Boolean Z3Py expressions

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, boolean-logic, z3py

I have some CNFs of Boolean expressions from the logic module in Sympy.
I get their Sympy expression trees with `srepr()` ([see documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/manipulation.html)).

Find below an example with two CNFs.

```
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy.logic.boolalg import And, Or, Not

# (a | ~c) & (a | ~e) & (c | e | ~a)
expr_1 = And(Or(Symbol('a'), Not(Symbol('c'))), Or(Symbol('a'), Not(Symbol('e'))), Or(Symbol('c'), Symbol('e'), Not(Symbol('a'))))

# (b | ~d) & (b | ~e) & (d | e | ~b)
expr_2 = And(Or(Symbol('b'), Not(Symbol('d'))), Or(Symbol('b'), Not(Symbol('e'))), Or(Symbol('d'), Symbol('e'), Not(Symbol('b'))))
```

I want to give those expression trees to a Z3Py solver as Boolean constraints.
For that, I think that need to:

1. transform `sympy.Symbol()` to `z3.Bool()`, and
2. transform the sympy logic operators to Z3 logic operators (e.g., `sympy.logic.boolalg.And()` to `z3.And()`)

Then, I would add the constraints to a Z3 solver to output a solution.

If we continue with the example, as I see it, we would have the two following constraints (I wrote explicitly that I use Z3 Boolean operators to avoid confusion with the Sympy ones):

```
import z3 as z3
from z3 import Bool

const_1 = z3.And(z3.Or(Bool('a'), z3.Not(Bool('c'))), z3.Or(Bool('a'), z3.Not(Bool('e'))), z3.Or(Bool('c'), Bool('e'), z3.Not(Bool('a'))))

const_2 = z3.And(z3.Or(Bool('b'), z3.Not(Bool('d'))), z3.Or(Bool('b'), z3.Not(Bool('e'))), z3.Or(Bool('d'), Bool('e'), z3.Not(Bool('b'))))
```

How could we parse Sympy Boolean expression trees for Z3Py in an automated fashion? Is there a better way to do it than what I presented as an example?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what brought you to try feeding sympy expression to Z3 solver?

Comment: Because of some research question :) I already had sympy expressions, and then we wanted to feed that to a SAT solver. It seemed like the least effort to do it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track. Essentially, you need to "compile" SymPy to Z3. This can be achieved in a variety of ways, but it's not a cheap/easy thing to do since you'd need to analyze large swaths of SymPy code. However, looks like your expressions are "simple" enough, so you can get away with a simple translator. Start by looking at how SymPy trees can be recursively processed: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/manipulation.html#recursing-through-an-expression-tree

If you're in a hurry, you can use Axel's program, given in the other answer. Here's a version that is probably a bit more idiomatic and easier to extend and more robust:

```py
import sympy
import z3

# Sympy vs Z3. Add more correspondences as necessary!
table = { sympy.logic.boolalg.And    : z3.And
        , sympy.logic.boolalg.Or     : z3.Or
        , sympy.logic.boolalg.Not    : z3.Not
        , sympy.logic.boolalg.Implies: z3.Implies
        }

# Sympy vs Z3 Constants
constants = { sympy.logic.boolalg.BooleanTrue : z3.BoolVal(True)
            , sympy.logic.boolalg.BooleanFalse: z3.BoolVal(False)
            }

def compile_to_z3(exp):
    """Compile sympy expression to z3"""
    pexp = sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr(exp)
    pvs  = {v: z3.Bool(str(v)) for v in pexp.atoms() if type(v) not in constants}

    def cvt(expr):
        if expr in pvs:
            return pvs[expr]

        texpr = type(expr)
        if texpr in constants:
            return constants[texpr]

        if texpr in table:
            return table[texpr](*map(cvt, expr.args))

        raise NameError("Unimplemented: " + str(expr))

    return cvt(pexp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    z3.solve(compile_to_z3("false"))
    z3.solve(compile_to_z3("a & ~b | c"))
    z3.solve(compile_to_z3("false >> (a & ~b | c)"))
```

This prints:

```
no solution
[c = False, b = False, a = True]
[]
```

You can add new functions to `table` to extend it as you see fit.

Comment: Nice! This ist truly more idiomatic compared to my sketch.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! What would you advice if the Boolean expressions are larger than the example? (You talked about being "simple enough" here, but what if it's not the case anymore?)

Comment: As long as all you have are `&`, `|`, `~`, the program I gave will work, no problems. But if you have more complicated SymPy expressions you’ll have to add custom translations for them, hopefully there’s something in Z3 that’s a close match. Try it out and let us know if you run into trouble.

Comment: @Aster The previous version didn't handle the constants `true`/`false`. I added support for those. Check out the new program.

Comment: Regarding "more complex" expressions: If all you care about is boolean-algebra, I think you can get away with just changing the definition of `table` to add whatever else combinators you need, mapping them to z3 equivalents. My concerns was more about general sympy: Numbers, functions, etc.; some of which can be translated to z3 in this way, but not all of it will be supported. (For instance `sin`/`cos` etc. don't have any SMTLib support.) So long as you stick to boolean-algebra, I think this program (with an extended `table` as necessary) should do the trick.

Comment: I understand better what you mean! That's not my case, indeed. Thank you very much for your detailed answers!

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't resist and implemented a basic converter.

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
from z3 import *

#  extract all variables and define a SymPy expression
def create_sympy_expression(expr):
    declare_sympy_symbols(expr)
    return parse_expr(expr)

#  assume all single-character operands as SymPy variables
dicz3sym = {}
def declare_sympy_symbols(expr):
    for c in expr:
        if 'a' <= c <= 'z':
            if not c in dicz3sym:
                dicz3sym[c] = z3.Bool(c)

def transform_sympy_to_z3(exp):
    params = [transform_sympy_to_z3(arg) for arg in exp.args]
    func = str(exp.func)
    if func == "And":
        return z3.And(params)
    elif func == "Not":
        return z3.Not(params[0])
    elif func == "Or":
        return z3.Or(params)
    elif exp.name in dicz3sym:
        return dicz3sym[exp.name]
    else:
        raise NameError("unknown/unimplemented operator: " + func)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    exp = create_sympy_expression("a & ~b | c")
    z3exp = transform_sympy_to_z3(exp)
    s = Solver()
    s.add(z3exp)
    if s.check() == sat:
        m = s.model()
        print("Solution found:")
        for v in dicz3sym:
            print(f"{v} = {m[dicz3sym[v]]}")
    else:
        print("No solution. Sorry!")
```

Comment: Comparing strings to identify classes is a bit brittle (and slow), though this is a good start! I've posted a modified version in my answer which should be more robust and hopefully faster and easier to use.